# DataGridTextColumn doesn't allow to enter "double" value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid

I have property `double? MyDouble { get .. set ... }`.
I've binded it in DataGridTextColumn:

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyDouble}" />
```

It works fine unless I add UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyDouble, 
                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

In this case I can't enter "." and add "double" value. How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: so with    'double?'   you can use "."?

Comment: Yes, I can use "." with "double?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall .NET 4.5 Beta. I've posted this bug to [Microsoft support](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/732397/datagridtextcolumn-doesnt-allow-to-enter-double-value).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to your windows localization settings. For example if you want to convert "1,65" under US localized windows to double, exception will be thrown. But when you want to convert the same string under Czech localization, it will proceed.

Is it really working without UpdateSourceTrigger set to PropertyChanged? I think it would just allow you to enter the "." but binding won't set the value to underlying context.

Comment: Without UpdateSourceTrigger it works. Now I'm trying to uninstall .NET 4.5 Beta.

Answer (score -1):

For those who havent found out any other solution i also found this:

[image: Screenshot]

The data type allows you to select what data type it is and chances are is that yours is set to `int32`.

Comment: You should always inline the images. Who knows what kind of image have you uploaded!

Comment: I see thanks for letting me know hope you didnt mark me down just for that. This might be the solution for a problem a lot of people are having and having it marked down makes it look as if its the wrong answer.