# WPF Datagrid DataGridTextColumn does not allow decimal

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit, wpf-4.0

I am not able to enter decimal values in DataGridTextColumn. Below link suggest that we cannot enter decimal values if UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged.

[WPF DataGridTextColumn binding doesn't accept decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985650/wpf-datagridtextcolumn-binding-doesnt-accept-decimals)

But my requirement is that I have to keep  UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged.

Please suggest.

Below is the code snippet for my Datagrid:

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CanUserResizeColumns="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataCollectionListView, Mode=TwoWay}"
      SelectionMode="Extended" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionUnit="Cell">                                                      
     <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColMyDataGrid" Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Path=Price, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource    ZeroToEmptyConverter}}" >
  <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />                                               
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="#BEFAC4"/>   
    </Style>
  </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
 </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: does it need to be `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`?

Comment: did you also try to bind to a textbox in a template column?

Comment: Can you also add the code of `ZeroToEmptyConverter` here?

Comment: Ultimately I had to change UpdateSoruceTrigger property to LostFocus. No other options work for me. Still looking for any solution for this kind of scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus then allow remove decimal point automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can code around the problem by adding a string property, 'PriceAsString', to the datagrid's ItemsSource model. Then convert the string to a decimal in the new property's setter and assign the value to Price. Then just bind the DataGridTextColumn to the PriceAsString Property. It's also necessary to add a conversion in the 'Price' property setter so that Price and PriceAsString are always synchronized.

The properties might look something like this

```
        private decimal? _price;
        public decimal? Price 
        { 
            get { return _price; } 
            set 
            {
                if (value != _price)
                {
                    _priceAsString = value.ToString();
                }

                _price = value;
            }
        }

        // Acts as a buffer for 'Price' so that the view doesn't remove decimals while typing in a control with 'UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged'
        private string _priceAsString;
        public string PriceAsString
        {
            get { return _priceAsString; }
            set
            {
                _priceAsString = value;
                Price = decimal.Parse(_priceAsString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
```

Admittedly I'm not crazy about this solution since it adds bloat to the model and complicates things a bit. But if you absolutely need to use UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, then maybe it's better than nothing...

If you do this you may also want to consider adding some text validation, since this will allow the text column to accept non-number/decimal characters.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `Delay` like 1 or 2 seconds in the `Binding`. This will delay the validation before it kicks off.

```
<DataGridTextColumn
 x:Name="ColMyDataGrid"
 Header="Price"
 Binding="{Binding Path=Price, Delay=1000,
           Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
           Converter={StaticResource ZeroToEmptyConverter}}" >
```

It's annoying because the user must check the decimal point again while typing but good for temporary solution in my case.

Or, you can go to the WPF App constructor and add this code:

```cs
public App()
{
     FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences
          .KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;
}
```